# Django post_save signal, created argument

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm having trouble accessing the `created` argument, from my `post_save` signal receiver.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Facility)
def add_times(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    created = kwargs.get('created', False)

    if isinstance(instance, Facility) and created:
        instance.add_opening_times()
```

When I call `save()` on a `Facility` instance, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\bin\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\bin\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
  File "C:\bin\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 192, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\git\SimplySport\facility\models.py", line 53, in update_stock
    instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
NameError: name 'created' is not defined
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: Did you restart your shell after changing the code?

Comment: Oh my word, no. I just re-imported the module. Problem solved, this works, thanks!

Comment: Imported modules are cached into `sys.modules`. In this case, I saw that the traceback didn't match the error message. Since the traceback is reconstructed from the source code files, this usually means that the source code files have changed after the code was compiled and loaded.